# Are martingales progressively measurable? (Application to square integrable martingales)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

This is an incredibly dumb question, but I'm not sure if I know the correct answer, and it doesn't seem to be stated anywhere on the internet, so here goes:

> Are martingales progressively measurable? (At least up to a modification?)

The answer should be yes if it is true, as I have read (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressively_measurable_process)), that every measurable and adapted process has a progressively measurable modification, since obviously martingales are measurable and adapted.

I ask because I want to deduce whether or not the space of locally $L^2-$bounded martingales is closed under integration with respect to Brownian motion. This seems to follow from Definition 3.1.4 p. 25, and Corollary 3.2.6 on p. 33 of Oksendal's *Stochastic Differential Equations*.

**EDIT:** The answer is almost certainly yes, since Definition 3.14 in Oksendal essentially states that: $f \in \mathcal{V}(S,T)$ if and only if: **(1)** $f$ is a measurable process, **(2)** $f$ is an adapted process, and **(3)** $f$ is bounded in $L^2$ on $[S,T]$. From **(1)** and **(2)** it should follow that $f$ has a progressively measurable version. Then from corollary 3.17 (Ito's Isometry) and condition **(3)** of Definition 3.14, it follows that the Ito integral with respect to Brownian motion *over a finite interval* $[S,T]$ is bounded in $L^2$, and then Corollary 3.2.6 gives us that it is a martingale, hence an $L^2$-bounded martingale.

> **Does this mean that if we restrict the class of integrands from** *"locally bounded progressively measurable processes"* **to** *"locally bounded and locally $L^2$ bounded progressively measurable processes"* **that the Ito integral with respect to Brownian motion is always a** (locally) **$L^2$-bounded martingale?**

Namely we get from the second result that any integral of a locally $L^2-$bounded progressively measurable process is a martingale. Also Ito's isometry has something to do with $L^2-$bounded martingales. But anyway the space wouldn't be closed under integration w.r.t. Brownian motion if the resulting martingale wasn't itself integrable w.r.t. Brownian motion.

---

---

In what follows, we assume the existence of an underlying filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge 0}$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

> **adapted process** - a process $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ such that $X_t : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$.
>
> **measurable process** - a process $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ such that the induced mapping $$X: \Omega \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad (\omega,t) \mapsto X_t(\omega)$$ is measurable *(= jointly measurable in $\Omega \times [0, \infty)$????)*.
>
> **progressively measurable process** - a process $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ such that, for every $t \in [0, \infty)$, the map $$[0,t] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \quad (s, \omega) \mapsto X_s(\omega)$$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.

Comment: Do you have a good source for explaining the difference between progressively measurable and adapted?

Comment: @bcf see my new edit

Comment: An adapted process is progressively measurable if it is right- or left-continuous. If the filtration with respect to which your process, $X$, is a martingale satisfies the usual conditions, then $X$ has a cadlag modification if and only if $t \mapsto E[X_t]$ is right-continuous. The latter is Doob's regularization theorem. Maybe this helps.